# How to select limit records from database for different unique values of column

Tags: sql

I have database which has column 'type' with restricted set of values(channel, packet, subscription, etc...) :

```
id, url, type
1   url1  channel
2   url2  packet
3   url3  subscription
4   url4  channel
......
101 url101 packet
```

I'd like to get limit number of records for every type: N for channel, N for packet etc records... Please explain me how to do it - the number of unique values for type may change.

Comment: First you have to decide which way you provide the query with Nx parameters the query should limit the number of rows to return for every type x.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= ?;
```

`?` is a placeholder for the number you want of each type.

Comment: But I have a lot of different types - I don't like to insert values by hands

Comment: You could put them in a csv and copy paste to your query and put that result where Gordon has the ?  (e.g. where seqnum in  ('a','b','c')  or you could import the list of conditions to a table and join on it

Comment: @RomanKazmin . . . There is no listing of types -- unless you want to filter them.  This returns <n> rows per type for all types in the table.  The `n` is the parameter.

Comment: I have made test but received the following error:
Error: near line : near "(": syntax error